# Disable blackout when open BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

If I can disable activity blackout when `BottomSheetDialogFragment` showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only add this line:

```
dialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
```